# Why this code does not print two "hello" when using multi process?

Tags: c, linux, process, multiprocessing

I am learning about multi process and know that when using fork() child process is created, and the child obtains copies of the parent’s stack, data, heap, and text segments.

So why this code below does not print two "hello"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int idata = 111; /* Allocated in data segment */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int istack = 222; /* Allocated in stack segment */
    pid_t childPid;
    idata *= 2;
    istack *= 2;
    printf("hello\n");

    switch (childPid = fork()) {
            case -1:
                    printf("fork fail\n");
                    exit(0);
            case 0:
                    idata *= 3;
                    istack *= 3;
                    break;
            default:
                    sleep(3); // Give child a chance to execute
                    break;
    }
    /* Both parent and child come here */

    printf("PID=%ld %s idata=%d istack=%d\n", (long) getpid(),
    (childPid == 0) ? "(child) " : "(parent)", idata, istack);

    exit(0);
}
```

The result is

hello

PID=591 (child)  idata=666 istack=1332

PID=590 (parent) idata=222 istack=444

why this code does not print two "hello"?

Comment: Child process starts its execution from the line where the `fork` is called

Comment: The program prints “hello” and then forks. Neither the parent nor the child resets to earlier code; they both continue from the fork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf("hello\n");` happens before `fork()`.

When the output is a terminal, `stdout` is line-buffered by default, it outputs 1 `hello` because `stdout` gets flushed on `\n`.

When the output is redirected into a file or a pipe, `stdout` is block-buffered by default, it outputs 2 `hello`s because both the parent and child processes have `hello` buffered and the buffers get flushed on `exit()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have one confuse. Why istack *= 2  happens before fork() but child process still perform this code?

Comment: @T1412 I cannot understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I mean that child process still perform istack*2

Comment: @T1412 The child process starts after the statement with `fork` and it gets a copy of `istack` with whatever value it had before `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

you're making `printf("hello\n");` before the call to the `fork()` function .

Answer (score 0):

Trace the program flow. First there is only one process executing this program. This process prints "hello". Next, there is a fork system call inside the switch statement. Now there are two processes, parent and child. The child is a clone of the parent. Everything, except the process id, is the same for both. Even the next instruction to be executed is the same for both. Both, the parent and child execute the switch statement next. The child never had a chance to print "hello".